# How to kill all sessions by a single click in PLSQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm using [PL/SQL Developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL_Developer).
Now I need to kill all sessions with a specific status(e.g. **INACTIVE**) in my oracle database by a single click. Currently I'm killing session one by one.
 My current strategy is

first GOTO ***sessions***

[image]

And then click right button of mouse and select ***kill*** row by row:

[image]

I've tried both ***Shift*** and ***CTR*** key to select multiple row at a time but they are failed to select multiple rows.

Expecting answer to save my time. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried selecting then all with shift key? or using ctrl key?

Comment: Why not just restart or bounce the database then you have no risk that you will be killing Oracle sessions.

Comment: @JorgeCampos already tried

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Most sessions are inactive most of the time.  That is perfectly normal.  Killing sessions merely for having a status of INACTIVE is going to cause lots of problems for users.

Comment: @kevinsky restart is not a solution for my case because I dont want to stop database for that and dont want to kill all sessions.

Comment: @JustinCave sometimes I need to kill some sessions to free resource in my test database.

Comment: What resources are you trying to free?  A session that is actually inactive will hold a tiny amount of resources.  Unless you are terribly concerned about a few MB of RAM or you have thousands of sessions, that doesn't make sense.  If you are concerned about resources for idle sessions, you probably want to move away from dedicated server sessions and use shared server.  If you have sessions that are holding large amounts of resources, that implies that you should figure out the handful of problem sessions and kill those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing inactive sessions can be done in 3 clicks with a custom template.

(If you really need a one-click solution you'll probably need to create a custom plugin using Delphi.  But that would take a lot of work.)

Once you create and get used to template it will only take a second to run one.  First, go to the Templates window, usually in the bottom-left-hand side of the screen.  Right-click on the background and select "New Template...".  Enter a name for the template.

[image: Crate PL/SQL Developer template]

Now enter this text.  It's a PL/SQL block that will kill all inactive sessions.

```
begin
    for sessions_to_kill in
    (
        select 'alter system kill session '''||sid||','||serial#||',@'||inst_id||''' immediate' v_sql
        from gv$session
        where status = 'INACTIVE'
            --Can't kill your current session.
            and not (sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid') and inst_id = sys_context('userenv', 'instance'))
    ) loop
        execute immediate sessions_to_kill.v_sql;
    end loop;
end;
```

To call the template, right-click somewhere in a SQL window, select "Insert Template" and the name.  Run the PL/SQL block after it appears in the SQL window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Idea. So far there is no alternative answer for my question. So I'm going to accept it as answer.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. You may also avoid an exception (trying kill your own session) using this: sid <> SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID')